# Metatransaction EIP-712 compliant reverted on Tether USDT Polygon contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, erc-20-approve, meta-transactions, eip712

I have a problem with the execution of a metatransaction EIP-712 compliant, I show you the backend code with ethers.js and the link of the contract on mainnet :slight_smile:

Contract : https://polygonscan.com/address/0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f

Code :

```
    
const ethers = require("ethers");

/**************************** SETUP ****************************/

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("RPC URL");

// Tether USDT address
const address = "0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f";

const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [
      { internalType: "address", name: "spender", type: "address" },
      { internalType: "uint256", name: "amount", type: "uint256" },
    ],
    name: "approve",
    outputs: [{ internalType: "bool", name: "", type: "bool" }],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
];

const signer = new ethers.Wallet("Approve Sender Priv Key", provider);

const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);

async function getSignature() {
  // Create transaction data
  const transaction = await contract.populateTransaction.approve(
    "Approve Receiver",
    "Amount"
  );

  // Get signer nonce
  const nonce = await contract.getNonce(signer.address);

  // Get Polygon Mainnet Chain ID
  const salt = ethers.utils.hexZeroPad(ethers.utils.hexValue(137 ?? 0), 32);

  // Create domain object
  const domain = {
    name: "UChildERC20Proxy",
    version: "1",
    verifyingContract: transaction.to,
    salt: salt,
  };

  // Create object according to MetaTransaction struct
  const types = {
    MetaTransaction: [
      {
        name: "nonce",
        type: "uint256",
      },
      {
        name: "from",
        type: "address",
      },
      {
        name: "functionSignature",
        type: "bytes",
      },
    ],
  };

  // Create message to be signed
  const message = {
    nonce: nonce,
    from: signer.address,
    functionSignature: transaction.data ?? "",
  };

  // Sign message
  const signature = await signer._signTypedData(domain, types, message);

  console.log(signature);

  // Retrieve v, r, s from previous signature
  const split = ethers.utils.splitSignature(signature);

  console.log(split);

  // Check address retrieved from the previous data
  const recoveredAddress = ethers.utils.verifyTypedData(
    domain,
    types,
    message,
    signature
  );

  console.log(recoveredAddress);
}

getSignature();
```

I have followed the EIP-712 and NativeMetaTransaction flux to populate the inputs of the executeMetaTransaction function, which is:

```
function executeMetaTransaction(
    address userAddress,
    bytes memory functionSignature,
    bytes32 sigR,
    bytes32 sigS,
    uint8 sigV
) public payable returns (bytes memory) {
    MetaTransaction memory metaTx = MetaTransaction({
        nonce: nonces[userAddress],
        from: userAddress,
        functionSignature: functionSignature
    });

    require(
        verify(userAddress, metaTx, sigR, sigS, sigV),
        "Signer and signature do not match"
    );

    // increase nonce for user (to avoid re-use)
    nonces[userAddress] = nonces[userAddress].add(1);

    emit MetaTransactionExecuted(
        userAddress,
        msg.sender,
        functionSignature
    );

    // Append userAddress and relayer address at the end to extract it from calling context
    (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = address(this).call(
        abi.encodePacked(functionSignature, userAddress)
    );
    require(success, "Function call not successful");

    return returnData;
}    function executeMetaTransaction(
    address userAddress,
    bytes memory functionSignature,
    bytes32 sigR,
    bytes32 sigS,
    uint8 sigV
) public payable returns (bytes memory) {
    MetaTransaction memory metaTx = MetaTransaction({
        nonce: nonces[userAddress],
        from: userAddress,
        functionSignature: functionSignature
    });

    require(
        verify(userAddress, metaTx, sigR, sigS, sigV),
        "Signer and signature do not match"
    );

    // increase nonce for user (to avoid re-use)
    nonces[userAddress] = nonces[userAddress].add(1);

    emit MetaTransactionExecuted(
        userAddress,
        msg.sender,
        functionSignature
    );

    // Append userAddress and relayer address at the end to extract it from calling context
    (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = address(this).call(
        abi.encodePacked(functionSignature, userAddress)
    );
    require(success, "Function call not successful");

    return returnData;
}
```

When I go on the WriteProxy tab of the contract, I set all the inputs in this way:

userAddress (address) : address who approves and needs the metatransaction to be paid by the relayer (the approve sender)
functionSignature (bytes) : function signature got from the backend script (signature)
sigR (bytes32), sigS (bytes32), sigV (uint8) : values got from the backend script (split)

Then I connect another wallet with funds but on Metamask says the transaction will revert, I don't know why because I think everything is fine...

Thanks to everyone who will help me :)

Answer (score 0):

We had to get a similar workflow working correctly at our start-up recently. One definite issue with your code is:

```
name: "UChildERC20Proxy",
```

should be:

```
name: "(PoS) Tether USD",
```

This field should be the result of calling the `name` method of the [Polygon USDT contract](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f#readProxyContract#F18). Apart from that, I believe the rest of your code is correct: in particular, you are forming `domain`, `types`, and `message` correctly.

As a suggestion, I would consider switching to human-readable abi and to ethers v6, to simplify things a bit, if possible.